How would you translate "hardcover" book?
I've noticed that Latin doesn't have a word for "hardcover book".
Google Translate translates it as "hardcover liber" which doesn't seem quite right.
When asking ChatGPT, I've got an answer: "Liber duri operculi" but yesterday, it told me there is no equivalent in Latin, but this is only approximation alongside with "Codex durus", which seems to me archaic and not appropriate translation for modern hardcovers.
Thanks.

My Swedish–Latin dictionary suggests (liber) "tegumento munitus". That may just be the author's invention. In any case, the distinction hardcover/softcover is decidedly modern, and a commonly accepted term may not exist. If you're making one up, be aware that a direct translation from English "hardcover" is not the only option. Swedish "inbunden" and French "relié" literally means "bound", conceptually prioritizing the spine rather than the cover.

I'm not aware of existing standard terminology, so the answer will depend heavily on the use context.
Suppose, for example, that you've written a book in Latin and you sell it on your Latin website.
If it comes in both hardcover and paperback forms, you need to articulate the distinction.
In that case I would call them simply liber durus and liber mollis.
In such context there's no reason to come up with anything more complicated; people who have bought books before will get the point and using more exotic words would confuse some buyers.
If you aim to give a technical account to professionals and enthusiasts working with books, you probably want something different.
Without specific context I can only guess.
In general I would go with the simplest understandable option, which is what I gave above.

Do you know of any other language (particular Romance language) that abbreviates in this way? A brief review of the usual suspects (French, Spanish, Italian, etc.) seems to show that there is always a word that specifies that the cover is hard.

@brianpck No, I'm not aware of other languages that keep it this simple. Perhaps an interesting data point is that a common Finnish term for softcover means "pocket book", leaving softness itself implicit. I fully admit that my proposal has no other precedent than my preference for simplicity.
